# Embed Image issue strip slash

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, stripslashes

I have a script which inputs form data then generates an email to the user who completes the form. The email goes to the email recipient all fine, but the image does not show.( I get a broken link icon in Mail).

I looked at the source code of the email when it arrived and it appears the backslashes where before the double quotes. How do I get this to work?

Email source code:

```
 <img src=\"https://amb.cbussuper.com.au/registration-test/images/sig.png\” /><br><br>
```

PHP Code:

```
    $message = "<html><body>";
    $message .= "<b>Thank you for registering for the meeting</b><br>";
    $message .= "-  Day: 28 October 2014<br>";
    $message .= "-  Time: 7pm<br><br>";
    $message .= "If you have any questions about the meeting please email email@address.com.au<br><br>";
    $message .= "Please do not reply - this is an automatically generated email.<br><br>";
    $message = stripcslashes($message); 
    $message .= '<img src="https://website.com.au/registration/images/sig.png" /><br><br>';
    $message .= "</body></html>";
```

Comment: Show us more code. We need to show your call to PHP Mailer.

Comment: Why is `"` and `”` different? Is that just a formatting issue when copy/pasting, or is that how it actually was? Just before the e-mail is actually sent, use `stipslashes` on the message to double-make sure: https://eval.in/197214

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple:
https://website.com.au/registration/images/sig.png
Not Found

The requested URL /registration/images/sig.png was not found on this server.
Apache Server at website.com.au Port 443

Please upload the file which you want to refer as an image ...

Comment: This may be true, but it's nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: You get the broken link because THE LINK IS BROKEN.
Please upload it, and check if this helps or not! (i gues it helps, i've tried the link on a broswer and it's ERROR404 !)

The other link (https://amb.cbussuper.com.au/registration-test/images/sig.png) is protected by password, so it will also give "broken image" if you try to use it, as the mail program can not access the file ...